# Restar los datos del primer día frente al último día del mes en SQL de todos los meses del año

Tags: sql, jquery, datatables, jquery-validate, report

Necesito una consulta para saber la resta de datos del primer día frente al último día del mes en SQL de todos los meses del año.

He utilizado SQL Server y esta es mi consulta actual:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATE = '2024-01-08';
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE = '2024-02-10';

SELECT 
    dm.Fecha,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia
FROM 
    Dato_Medidor dm
LEFT JOIN 
    Dato_Medidor dp ON DATEADD(YY, - 1, dm.Fecha) = dp.Fecha
                    AND dm.Linea = dp.Linea
                    AND dp.Fecha BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@FechaInicial, -1)) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@FechaFinal,-1))
                    AND DATEPART(HOUR, dp.Fecha) = 7
                    AND DATEPART(MINUTE, dp.Fecha) = 0
WHERE 
    dm.Fecha BETWEEN EOMONTH(@FechaInicial) AND EOMONTH(@FechaFinal)
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, dm.Fecha) = 7
    AND DATEPART(MINUTE, dm.Fecha) = 0
GROUP BY 
    dm.Fecha
ORDER BY 
    dm.Fecha
```

Este es mi resultado actual:

| MONTH -- | ELFO_010_Disco | ELFO_009_FBW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | 100 | 300 |
| 01/02/2024 | 100 | 400 |
| 01/03/2024 | 400 | 500 |

este es lo que requiero:

| MONTH | ELFO_010_Disco | ELFO_009_FBW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JENUARY | 100 | 200 |
| February | 300 | 100 |
| March | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Deberías colocar que motor de base de datos que estas utilizado MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle u otro, (asumo que es SQL Server) y modificar los tags que utilizaste en tu pregunta, porque jquery no tienen nada que ver con tu consulta. Saludos.